# dijit.MenuItem values are auto-highlighted... how to stop this?

Tags: menu, dojo, highlight, menuitem

I am using Dojo 1.3.1 and have a dijit.Menu with several dijit.MenuItem items.  The menu is displayed as a context menu when the user right-clicks on items that were bound to the menu using (dijit.byId("contextmenu_pf")).bindDomNode(...).  All works well, but frequently when the menu is displayed, one or more of the menu items are highlighted (aside from the first one).  This seems to be random and has no relationship to previously selected items. Some of the highlighted menu options are even displayed.

Has anyone seen this behavior and/or know how to stop it from happening?

Thanks - Peter

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, filed as http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10339.

The attachment in that link also lists some workaround code.